# Cycles bake normal image is distorted

Tags: baking

I'm trying to bake this mesh as a normal, but the bake is no where near the image of the mesh. I've tried changing the Max Ray Distance but the result is still distorting. Here's the file if someone would like to have a look.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently baking the high-poly object to itself, which will give weird result as the surface that will scan the high-poly is the high-poly itself, you'd better bake the high-poly to the low-poly:

- Select the high-poly, shift select the low-poly
- Enable *Selected to Active*
- As the high-poly is a bit bigger give it a bit of *Extrusion* and *Ray Distance*, not too much, the value is in scene units

[image]

What it gives:

[image]

Comment: Hi moonboots, What version of Blender are you using?

Comment: 2.91 I guess (maybe Extrusion is a new feature), what version do you use? did you succeed?

Comment: I'm currently on 2.90.1. I believe my GPU is not doing a good job, I also sent the file to another friend, he got the same result like you, I'm only one getting the glitchy result, cant wait for a new build... In case you're wondering my PC is a 2009 build, old old specs.

Comment: it works fine with 2.90.1 here, make sure to select the high-poly then shift select the low-poly, and use the exact same settings